# Gained a privilege... except not

Tags: support, reputation, notifications

Earlier today I received a notification that I'd gained the privileges associated with 1,000 rep... except my rep has been 989 for several days.

I'm not sure what to make of the situation. Any ideas what's going on?

Answer (score 5):

Most likely you were voted up twice, then the voter(s) changed their mind and removed the vote again. See e.g. [Notification for moderator tools went off too early](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/70875/notification-for-moderator-tools-went-off-too-early).

Comment: Or maybe one person accepted an answer temporarily?

Comment: @tttppp - Good thinking. That sounds highly likely.